# How to get values from wordpress listings and use them in javascript array?

Tags: php, javascript, array

I'm trying to get values (latitude, longitude and an image) from the WordPress database and put it into a javascript array.

Unfortunately I'm a newbie at Javascript and PHP!

Here is the code I have so far:

**getdata.php:**

```
<?php
    require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php' );
    require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );  
?>
```

**distance.php:**

```
<?php
  include 'getdata.php';
?>
<html>
<head>
<script  type="text/javascript">

  <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'listing', 'p' => $post_id ); ?>
  values = [ <?php
                            $listing_marker_loop = new WP_Query( $args );

                            while ( $listing_marker_loop->have_posts() ) : $listing_marker_loop->the_post(); 

                            $address = get_field('location');

                            global $post;
                            // load all 'categories' terms for the post

                            endwhile;
  ?>];

  alert(values[1]);

</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to get it to give me an alert, so that I know I'm on the right track!

Can someone tell me how to make this work?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Latitude Longitude + Image looks like you want to build your own Google Map? In this case, maybe you can use this:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Comment: Not Google maps; open source, but yes a map. How would I include that in my script?

Comment: Do you want to use the map on your wordpress site, or externally?

Comment: I'm using it on the wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Changed the code to be used in a plugin.

Okay, with the info you provided, you can do something like this:

Step 1) Put your Javascript Map Loading stuff into a .js file. Save it somewhere in your plugin directory, like "myplugin/mapscript.js"

Step 2) create a file in your plugin directory, like "myplugin/myplugin.php".
Insert the Plugin header so that it can be recognized by wordpress:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: My Superawesome Map stuff Plugin
 * Description: Does Maps and Stuff
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: YOUR_NAME
 * License: GPL2
 */
```

Insert a function in your plugins myplugin.php, where you register & enqueue the script.

```
function mapstuff_load_scripts() {
 if(is_singular()) {
 global $post;  
 wp_enqueue_script('mapstuff-script', plugins_url( 'mapscript.js', __FILE__ ));
    wp_localize_script('mapstuff-script', 'mapstuff_script_vars', array(
            'lat' => get_post_meta($post->ID,'lat',TRUE),
            'lng' => get_post_meta($post->ID,'lng',TRUE),
            'addrimg' => get_post_meta($post->ID,'addrimg',TRUE)
        )
    );
 }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mapstuff_load_scripts');
```

I added the conditional is_singular to ensure this is only loaded on post/page view, not on search and index pages.

Step 3) Add the code for a shortcode in the plugin, so you can insert it on your page/post/wherever

```
add_shortcode('awesomemap','do_awesome_map');
function do_awesome_map($args = array()){
   $returnage = "THE STUFF THAT NEEDS TO BE INSERTED FOR THE MAP TO LOAD";
   return $returnage;
}
```

Step 4) Your localized vars will be in an javascript array, so change your mapscript to use these vars like this:

```
 alert(mapstuff_script_vars.lng);
 alert(mapstuff_script_vars.lat);
 alert(mapstuff_script_vars.addrimg);
```

Step 4) Upload, insert the shortcode [awesomemap] in your page/post, success ! ;)

Happy Coding,

Kuchenundkakao

Comment: The latitude, longitude and image are stored in a wordpress post, will this script get these variables from a post?

Comment: I need to do this without editing the theme. So I guess, it would either be through a plugin, or if I could make it stand alone it would be better. I was planning on accessing the map through an iFrame.

Comment: I edited the answer so you can use it in a plugin.

Comment: This code doesn't work for me. The alert comes up blank.

Comment: Look into the sourcecode of the page. are the custom fields lng, lat and addrimg set for the page?